# Fix apple macbook pro 10.6.8

Tags: google-chrome

I have a Mac Book Pro 10.6.8 and I cant operate safari, and chrome is outdated? Is there anythingI can do, or do I just need a new computer? I was told my lap top was ancient.

Comment: "10.6.8" is the version of OS X that your MacBook Pro is running; it is not the model of your MacBook. To find the model, select "About this Mac" from the Apple Menu, and read model information from the displayed box.

Comment: Well you need to give more information. From the menu bar, can you select `About This Mac` and post the model/year/screen size? For example, my computer is a `iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011)`. Have you also considered running Windows 10 or a version of linux such as Ubuntu? Linux usually is free. Windows you can try for free, but in the end you have to buy a license.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that your laptop is as old as the last Snow Leopard OS (10.6.8) that makes it 7 years old, and well into the age where it can be expected to stop working without warning. Browsers that ran on Snow Leopard are no longer supported by many websites so if you want to keep using it, you will be limited to mail, documents and basic internet usage.

So yes, whoever said your laptop was ancient was correct. Time for new hardware.

Good news is performance is way up, and prices are down. For example, My Air boots in 8 seconds and runs for 12 hours on the battery.

Do you have a backup of your laptop? My guess is No. Go buy an external drive and run Time Machine before your 7 year old internal drive decides to quit on you.

Comment: Your fourth paragraph is excellent advice.